# Hardware IDs using VB 6

Tags: vb6, hardware

It's a long time that I have given up MS platform and was working on open source, now I'm in a situation where I need user Hardware info. All hardware IDs of all devices of system including BIOS info. so I decided to go for VB6. It's easy in other languages, but they need dot net framework installed. How can this be done in VB6 alone.

Answer (score 3):

Use Windows WMI:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx

There you can query for quite some bit of information. Here is some sort of how-to which  happen to be written for Visual Basic Script

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394587%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I checked it, I need hardware ID , if you go to device manger, and click on properties, You will find the ID in detail tab. That is what I need for all devices, installed or uninstalled on system.

Comment: +1. Second link gives examples of how to get various device ids